# Multiple threads execution order

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having some issues understanding why when I create an object several times that implements the runnable interface, and I created them on `@Test` when I call that objects `start()` it runs first the `@Test` and then it goes the run method if the objects.

Here is the code:

```
public class Tests extends {
     @Test(testName = "754")
    public void concurrenciaGuardarArticuloTMP() throws Exception {
        try {
            this.codigoBarras =this.generarCodigoDeBarra();
            System.out.println(codigoBarras);
            logger.info("Codigo de barras generado fue ::: " + codigoBarras);
            GuardarArticuloTMP articulo1 = new GuardarArticuloTMP(GuardarArticuloTMP.TMP.TMP_CODIGO_BARRA,"TMP, Hilo 1", codigoBarras,35);
            GuardarArticuloTMP articulo2 = new GuardarArticuloTMP(GuardarArticuloTMP.TMP.TMP_CODIGO_BARRA,"TMP, Hilo 2", codigoBarras,37);
              articulo1.start();
            articulo2.start();
            logger.info("Codigo de barras generado fue ::: " + codigoBarras);
            System.out.println("Codigo de barras generado fue ::: " + codigoBarras);
            logger.info(writeDTO(articulo1.getArticulo()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error guardando Articulo.", ex);
            this.setExecutionDetail(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And GuardarArticulos Class:

```
public class GuardarArticuloTMP extends Setup implements Runnable{

    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    private String codigoBarras;
    private int numeroCaja;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GuardarArticulo.class);

    /**
     * @param pThreadName nombre del hilo
     * @param pCodigoBarras codigo de barras
     * @param pNumeroCja numero de caja para el local
     */
    public GuardarArticuloTMP(TMP tmp, String pThreadName, String pCodigoBarras, int pNumeroCja) {
        this.threadName = pThreadName;
        this.codigoBarras = pCodigoBarras;
        this.numeroCaja = pNumeroCja;
        this.tmp = tmp;
        initLogger();
    }

    /**
     * Crea un articulo
     * @return nos devuelve un articulo
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private ArticuloFacadeDTO crearArticulo() throws Exception {
        //creates Articulo
        return toSave;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Corriendo " + this.threadName.toUpperCase() + " !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        logger.info("Corriendo " + this.threadName.toUpperCase() + " !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(50);
            logger.info("estoy en el run por crear el articulo");
            ArticuloFacadeDTO toSave = crearArticulo();
            writeDTO(toSave);
            mgr.guardarArticuloFacade(toSave);
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Error::: ",ex);
        }
    }

public void start()
    {
        logger.info("Empezado el thread " + this.threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.setPriority(10);
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

What I'm expecting is that after I call all the `starts()`, it starts on the threads then finish running the `@Test` method, so I make the validations I require.

Comment: you haven't described the actual problem you are having, nor have you include the implementation of the start() method.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really understand what the issue is. It seems to me that you might have some misconceptions about how multithreading works in java. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You state what you are expecting but you don't state what the program actually did.  Did the threads start?

Comment: Yes the threads start, after the concurrenciaGuardarArticuloTMP finsihed.

Comment: What condition is your test supposed to confirm? There is no `assertEquals` call or anything. What is considered success or failure? Should your test function wait for the threads to end and confirm the results?

Comment: Calling `Thread.start()` will create a new execution stack and comes back to the main thread and continues with the next step in `main`. It doesn't wait for the spawned threads `run()` to complete. If you want to co-ordinate access then you need to use any of the constructs like `join() , wait/notify, countdownlatch or semaphoes`

Comment: So on the start() I should do a t.join() ?

Comment: No after start, you should call t1.join() in main(), so that main will wait for the completion of t1's run()

Comment: so after starting all the thread I need, to each thread ill do join()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no execution order in Java multithreading if you use the `Runnable` interface. There is no guarantee that `articulo1` will finish before `articulo2`.

The problem with `@Test`: It runs on a separate thread so the test method finishes long before your `Runnable`s finish.

I suggest you should really read through the official [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) trail on the Oracle webpage.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem but you can't assure a certain order among the threads unless you make use of some kind of flag.

It's probably not the best solution but if it is to be applied on a small project it can serve you.

For example you can use a Global/Static variable or the available constructs like `join or countdownlatches` to make that.

1. Lets see an example with a static variable called "A".
2. Every time you create a new thread, increment a variable named "B"
   and pass that variable value as an argument to the new thread.
3. If the valued passed, thread.B is equal to the Static variable A then
   it is time to run the thread, incrementing the static variable A in
   the end.
4. If thread.B is not equal to A, then the thread waits for A to be
   equal to B.

Hope it helps you! :)

Comment: How exactly do you think you can order the execution using static variable ? Can you pls explain that ?

Comment: The static variable is called "A".
Every time he creates a new thread he increments a variable named "B" and pass that variable value as an argument to the new thread. 

If the B value inside the thread is equal to the Static variable A then it's time to run it and in the end it will increment the static variable. If it is not equal, then the thread waits for the variable A to be equal to B. 

Please correct me if i'm totally wrong! :)

Comment: Well your idea is good but when you actually implement it, you'll see that static is not such a good choice, you need to synchronize access to static variable to make it work as per your expectations but it has the issue of thread contention. Also, you need to make sure that you always read updated static variable, need to run a loop to check for the variable update and act on it. It's a bit complicated but if you use `volatile` and `atomics` correctly, you might be able to do it :) But instead of re-inventing the wheel, you can just use existing constructs like `join or countdownlatches`

Comment: The reason for downvotes might be because your answer doesn't solve the OP's issue as you didn't explain it properly. You need to provide a good solution or at least guide him in the proper direction :) Edit your answer to reflect that

Comment: Oh I see. Didn't knew about those constructs, now I know. Thank you very much @Arkantos ! :)